# Why can AtomicUsize's fetch_max return a value greater than its argument?

Tags: rust

From the description of AtomicUsize's [fetch_max](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.fetch_max), it seems like the return value should always be smaller than or equal to the argument passed to the `val` parameter.

However, consider the following code:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;

const fn generate_bools() -> [bool; 100] {
    // An array of false values, except for certain indexes.
    let mut bools = [false; 100];
    bools[2] = true;
    bools[7] = true;
    bools[12] = true;
    bools[14] = true;
    bools[22] = true;
    bools[30] = true;
    bools[36] = true;
    bools[41] = true;
    bools[43] = true;
    bools[53] = true;
    bools[56] = true;
    bools[63] = true;
    bools[72] = true;
    bools[79] = true;
    bools[82] = true;
    bools
}

const BOOLS: [bool; 100] = generate_bools();

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    // Spawn 10 threads, for counter increments of +1 to +10 inclusively.
    for inc in 1..=10 {
        let counter = counter.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
            // Load the current counter and add the increment for this thread.
            let current = counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst);
            let new = current + inc;

            // Wait for a random duration between 100 and 355 ms.
            let random = rand::thread_rng().gen::<u8>() + 100;
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(random as u64));

            // If the array is true at that index, "fetch_max" it!
            let is_true = BOOLS[new];
            if is_true {
                let old = counter.fetch_max(new, Ordering::SeqCst);
                println!("old: {:02} / new: {:02}", old, new);
            }
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
        });
    }
    // Put main thread to sleep for 60s to give time for the children threads.
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(60));
}
```

When I run it, I get unexpected results. Here are two samples:

```
old: 00 / new: 02
old: 02 / new: 07
old: 07 / new: 14
old: 14 / new: 22
old: 22 / new: 30
old: 30 / new: 36
old: 36 / new: 43
old: 43 / new: 53
old: 53 / new: 63
old: 63 / new: 72
old: 72 / new: 56 <--
old: 72 / new: 79
old: 79 / new: 82
```

```
old: 00 / new: 02
old: 02 / new: 07
old: 07 / new: 12
old: 12 / new: 14
old: 14 / new: 22
old: 22 / new: 30
old: 30 / new: 36
old: 36 / new: 43
old: 43 / new: 41 <--
old: 43 / new: 53
old: 53 / new: 56
old: 56 / new: 63
old: 63 / new: 63
old: 63 / new: 72
old: 72 / new: 79
old: 79 / new: 82
```

I understand that the "new" values might not always go up, because there might be a race condition with the `fetch_max` and `println!` statements. For example, thread A can do the `fetch_add`, then thread B can do the `fetch_add` and the `println!`, then thread A can do the `println!`.

What I don't understand is how the `old` value can be strictly greater than the `new` value!

Comment: `fetch_max` does not return the maximum value. It simply returns the value that was previously stored in the `AtomicUsize`.

Comment: Take a look at the [second example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.fetch_max).

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood the meaning of the return value but it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is not the max of the current value and the argument.

The returned value is always the previous value of the atomic, whether that was the larger or smaller of the two values. For example:

```rust
let x = AtomicUsize::new(1);
let new = 0;
let old = x.fetch_max(new, Ordering::SeqCst);
assert_eq!((old, new), (1, 0));
// `x` still contains `1`
```